# How to access R session's variables from inside quarto file

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I'm using quarto as an alternative to rmarkdown to generate reports using R. However, I'm not sure how to access R objects already created before calling the `quarto_render` function. For example, in the below

```
var1=5
quarto::quarto_render(input="Audit.qmd")
```

i want to access `var1` from inside `Audit.qmd` file. But `Audit.qmd` does not recognise `var1`.Not sure how to do this. In Rmarkdown this can be done naturally. Quarto being language independent, doesn't make it that simple. I can store those variables as rds objects, and then import it back from inside qmd file, but is there a simpler way by which all the objects are accessed from qmd session?

Comment: Could you please share the code of your Audit file?

Comment: \`\`\`{r}
print(var1)
\`\`\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has just been answered by Posit employee at [R studio community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-access-r-sessions-variables-from-inside-quarto-file/163019/2).